# Jitsi Meet works on Firefox and Microsoft Edge but not on Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, jitsi-meet

I use jitsi meet in my angular project, but face a problem with google chrome.
I tried it on firefox and microsoft edge, it works good.

```
022-01-19T13:00:01.737Z [JitsiMeetJS.js] <Object.getGlobalOnErrorHandler>:  UnhandledError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'Gp(...)' as it is undefined. Script: null Line: null Column: null StackTrace:  TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'Gp(...)' as it is undefined.
    at Object.changeLocalDisplayName (https://teamjoin.de/libs/app.bundle.min.js?v=5764:138:559226)
    at Object.display-name (https://teamjoin.de/libs/app.bundle.min.js?v=5764:138:562587)
```

```
conference.js:3085 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'Gp(...)' as it is undefined.
    at Object.changeLocalDisplayName (conference.js:3085:17)
    at Object.display-name (API.js:138:28)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I try to use Google Chrome 97 x86 version, and it works. On 97 x64 version jitsi no video and sound.

https://www.google.com/chrome/?standalone=1&platform=win

Answer (score 0):

Update your chrome.  I am running version Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (64-bit) it works fine